# sql combining two columns one of which is a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have the following sql code (ms sql server 2008)

```
select (analysisno + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + description + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + formdate) as columnA
```

from Old_Analysis_Data 
order by formdate

I get the following error *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

AnalysisNo is a varchar(10)
description is a varchar(500) 
formdate is a datetime
(not my table, its an old one)

Any ideas, as cant find an answer on google.

Comment: You will most likely need to convert the date to a varchar with a TO_CHAR function depending on what flavor of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the time to a string using Convert before concatenation:

```
SELECT ( analysisno + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + description + ' ' + '-' + ' ' 
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), formdate, 100) ) AS columnA 
FROM 
     Old_Analysis_Data 
ORDER BY 
     formdate
```

In this case, 100 is a style that sets datestamp format to mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM) as an example

See  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: spot on cheers, I changed the 100 to 105 to get what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select (analysisno + ' - ' + description + ' - ' 
+ convert(varchar(100),formdate)) as columnA
from Old_Analysis_Data order by formdate
```

Comment: the query doesnt error but the date format needs to be 25/04/2013 preffrably

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating `formdate` directly, convert it to string first,

```
convert(varchar(15), formdate, 103)
```

which gives you the following format

```
dd/MM/yyyy
```